# Android ListView running an event on Item Long Click Release

Tags: android, events, android-listview, touch, listener

I'm using an OnItemClickListener and an OnItemLongClickListener in a ListView, now i'm searching a way to detect the release action after the OnItemLongClick, what's the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html) () (mainly [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html#ACTION_UP), you should be looking for `ACTION_UP`):

> **public static final int ACTION_UP**
>
> Added in API level 1 getAction() value: the key has been released.
>
> Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

Something like:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // do something on ACTION_UP.
        return true;
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}
```

Comment: That's a good point, but i need to be absolutely sure that this release event will be called, terminating an action that begins with the LongClick. If i'll opt for a KeyEvent i'll probably use it on the ListView itself, listView.setOnKeyListener(); would be safe enough to use?

Comment: You can change the name of the method from `onKeyDow` to `onKeyLongPress` and keep the body of the function, this will suffice

Answer (score 7):

While i accepted @g00dy answer i found that this solution fits my needs better, and keeps my code in one place.

inside the Activity where i setup the listView i'm doing this:

```
MyOnLongClickListener myListener = new MyOnLongClickListener(this);
listView.setOnItemLongClickListener(myListener);
listView.setOnTouchListener(myListener.getReleaseListener());
```

all the magic happens inside "MyOnLongClickListener":

```
public class MyOnLongClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemLongClickListener {

    private View.OnTouchListener mReleaseListener = new OnReleaseListener();
    private boolean mEnabled = false;
    private Context mContext;

    public MyOnLongClickListener(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onItemLongClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        Toast.makeText(mContext, "OnLongClick", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        mEnabled = true;
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Returns a listener for the release event.
     * @return
     */
    public View.OnTouchListener getReleaseListener() {
        return mReleaseListener;
    }

    /**
     * Listener for the Release event.
     */
    private class OnReleaseListener implements View.OnTouchListener {
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View view, MotionEvent motionEvent) {
            if(motionEvent.getAction() == android.view.MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                if(mEnabled) {
                    Toast.makeText(mContext, "Release", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    /* Execute... */
                    mEnabled = false;
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    }

}
```