# Android swap two itemViews in a ListView

Tags: android, android-listview

What is the best way (Compatible with API 8+) to swap two item's views in a ListView?

I've got a ListView and two custom item view's XML, normally the ListView is preloaded with

```
normalItemView
```

but when i long-click the item it must change view to become a:

```
longClickedItemView
```

when the user release his finger from the screen, it must return to a

```
normalItemView
```

I've already implemented the code to detect the user actions of long click and release (See [Android ListView running an event on Item Long Click Release](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18145172/android-listview-running-an-event-on-item-long-click-release/18146297#18146297)) but i don't know how to replace the entire item's view and change it with another view.

Questions are:

- What's the best and cross-version way to do this?
- Could it be possible to animate this swap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must use a viewgroup as an item of the listview and insert your layout into. So, when you implement 'delete', take the reference of viewgroup to remove the layout and then add the new view. About animation, you can use the Google's standard that you find [here](http://developer.android.com/training/animation/layout.html).